# How can I import scss into my Vue components?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I am trying to import my app.scss into my application.vue but I keep getting the error that the alias sass is not recognized. I looked online on how to add the alias to my mix file and I have the following webpack.mix.js. In my vue component I have the following code

```
<style lang="scss">
    @import 'sass/app.scss';
    html, body{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        background-color: $secondary-color;
    }
</style>
```

And in my webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig({
   resolve: {
      alias: {
         '@': path.resolve(__dirname,'/resources/js'),
         'sass': path.resolve(__dirname, '/resources/assets/sass')
      },
   },
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

I tried changing the alias to `~` but that did not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add a global scss file in Vue.JS that will compile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158207/how-do-i-add-a-global-scss-file-in-vue-js-that-will-compile)

Comment: It didn't work for me. I stored the scss in assets/scss/mixi.scss. In my `<style lang="scss" scoped>`I have `@import "./assets/scss/mixin";`. When calling `yarn serve`I get the error `Syntax Error: SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import` showing the path `@import "./assets/scss/mixin";`. I'm using vue cli.

Answer (score 5):

**Just simply import the scss file in your selected component in the following way. It works for me. I hope it will help you**

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  @import "./path/app.scss"; //Here i add extra "./"(current directory)
</style>
```

Comment: I needed to omit .scss in the filename for import to work

Answer (score 1):

I've used 2 separate approaches.

1. Use [style-resources-loader](https://github.com/yenshih/style-resources-loader).

In your `vue.config.js`:

```js
{
  //...
  pluginOptions: {
    'style-resources-loader': {
      preProcessor: 'scss',
      patterns: [resolve(__dirname, 'src/path/to/css/*.scss')],
    },
  },
  //...
}
```

2. Import the `scss` files in your `main.js` file, which just looks something like: `import './styles/path/to/file/app.scss';` as a js import at the top of the file.

Both of these approaches will effectively use your `scss` file globally without importing in each individual component.