# How to add scss files to Vue project globally 2020

Tags: vue.js, npm, sass, vue-cli

I am trying to add global scss variables to my vue project.

I found [here](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-import-a-sass-file-into-every-vue-component-in-an-app/)(css tricks) and [here](https://vueschool.io/articles/vuejs-tutorials/globally-load-sass-into-your-vue-js-applications/)(vue school) that what i have to do is to install sass-loader running `npm i node-sass sass-loader`in the command line.

I also need in my project a `vue.config.js` file with the following :

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `@import "@/styles/_variables.scss";`
      }
    }
  }
};
```

where `_variables.scss` is the file that i want to import globally.

When i run `npm run build` in my project i get this error :

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: semicolons aren't allowed in the indented syntax.
  ╷
1 │ @import "@/styles/_variables.scss";
  │                                   ^
  ╵
```

If i erase the semicolon :

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: expected ";".
  ╷
1 │ @import "@/styles/_variables.scss"
  │
```

If found [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158207/how-do-i-add-a-global-scss-file-in-vue-js-that-will-compile) that says that depending on my sass-loader version i have to change the `prependData` to `data`, where prependData is for `"sass-loader": "^8.0.2"` and `data` for `"sass-loader": "^7.*.*"`

I think the problem is somewhere in here as my sass-loader version is 6.13.4 according to

```
npm sass-loader -v
```

When i run `npm update sass-loader` i don't recieve any message, but the version is still 6.13.4

Accorging to [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader) the latest sass-loader version is 9.0.2

Does anyone know what am i doing wrong ?

My repository is [here](https://github.com/ignacioambia/tadoo)

Comment: i'm not sure if this is still the way to do it but I know at some point they split sass and scss options.  can you try changing `loaderOptions.sass` to `loaderOptions.scss` and see what happens?

Comment: WOOOOOW! It worked!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They split scss & sass options in vue-cli 4.0.0-beta.3 see [this github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4116#issuecomment-523374193).

```
...
   loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        prependData: `@import "@/styles/_variables.scss";`
      }
    }
...
```

Answer (score 4):

In the latest version of `sass-loader`, `data` or `prependData` will not work. Try `additionalData` instead

```
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
        @import "@/assets/styles/_responsive.scss";
        @import "@/assets/styles/_element-variables.scss";
        `
      },
   }
}
```