# Importing global scss style in Vue application together with separate mixin and variable scss files

Tags: vue.js, sass

I am building Vue 3 app with scss. I have 3 stylesheet files - `_mixins.scss`, `_variables.scss` and `base.scss`. I am importing the mixins and variables files in `vue.config.js` as I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54158207/how-do-i-add-a-global-scss-file-in-vue-js-that-will-compile), so I can use these mixins and variables in all my other components without needing to import them manually in all components.

However, I have also `base.scss` file, where I want to have global styles for my website (e.g. general styles for headings, etc.). I do not want to import this file in `vue.config.js`, because it would mean, that this file would be repeatedly included in all my components. So I tried to import it in `App.vue` via `@use "styles/base";` or in `main.js` using `import "styles/base.scss";`.

Unfortunately in both cases, Sass compiler throws this error:

```
Syntax Error: SassError: @use rules must be written before any other rules.
  ╷
6 │ @use "styles/base";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  D:\PWND\pwnd_ui_poc_js\src\App.vue 6:1  root stylesheet
```

I do not really know, how I should do it correctly. For the sake of completeness, I am including the base structure of my files:

```
// _variables.scss
$baseGreen: #24ff00;

// _mixins.scss
@forward "variables";

@mixin section-heading {
  color: $baseGreen;
}

// base.scss
@forward "mixins";
@forward "variables";

.section {
  color: $baseGreen;
  
  &-heading {
    @include section-heading();
  }
}
```

If you have any idea, how I should do this correctly, I would really appreciate your help. Thank you! :)

Comment: This is not the best way, but you can try change `@use` to standard `@import`.

Comment: @Daniel Thank you, somehow I got this working using ```@import``` in App.vue and deleting the two ```@forward``` in ```base.scss```. I was surprised, that I can use the variables in ```base.scss``` even though I removed the two ```@forward```s. I guess it's because it is imported in App.vue, from where I can access these variables, because of my ```vue.config.js``` configuration. I still think it's not ideal solution, but at least better, than write my global scss code to App.vue. If you have any other ideas of improvement, I would be glad to hear them. Thank you once more! :)

Comment: I've added an answer with my configuration within `vue.config.js`

Answer (score 2):

I'm using that configuration to load global variables for any component:

**vue.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      sass: {
        prependData: `@import '@/scss/_variables';`,
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this does not solve my problem, as I want to have just ```_variables.scss``` and ```_mixins.scss``` files in ```vue.config.js```. The main problem is importing the ```base.scss``` file, that I do not want to import in ```vue.config.js```, because it would be repeated in all my components.